# Strange Behavior of Form.Controls.OfType

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Form that gets built at run time where the user enters some data and either submits the data or cancels. The Form consists of a TableLayoutPanel with controls on it.

I add the Submit and Cancel buttons as follows.

```
TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel
{
       ColumnCount = 3,
       RowCount = gridObj.ColList.Count() + 1,
       Height = 800,
       Width = 800
 };

//other controls for user input...

    Button submitButton = new Button();
    submitButton.Text = "Submit";
    submitButton.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => { SubmitClick(sender, EventArgs, gridObj); };
    panel.Controls.Add(submitButton, 0, CurrentRow);
    this.AcceptButton = (submitButton);

    Button CancelButton = new Button();
    CancelButton.Text = "Cancel";
    panel.Controls.Add(CancelButton, 3, CurrentRow);
    this.CancelButton = (CancelButton);
```

There is a case where it is necessary to remove the buttons from the form. I do so with the following code.

```
private void RemoveExistingButtons(TableLayoutPanel panel)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            panel.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        }
    }
```

The way it looks to me this should find and remove each button from panel.
However it only removes the submit button.
The cancel button is not removed.

I was playing around with it and by adding another foreach, the cancel button gets removed by the second foreach.

```
private void RemoveExistingButtons(TableLayoutPanel panel)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            panel.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        }
        foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            panel.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        }
    }
```

I've tested this method with other control types, and they successfully remove multiple controls with only one loop, the way it 'should' work.

```
 private void RemoveExistingControls(TableLayoutPanel panel)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {
            panel.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        }
        foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            panel.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        }
    }
```

I'm quite confused about this. Am I overlooking something simple?

Comment: Did you try `foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList())`?

Comment: It is a well known rule. Do not change the collection that you are enumerating over.

Comment: Unlike other framework collection types, ControlCollection does not throw an exception when you continue iterating after having modified the collection.  In effect you'll skip the next control.  Either make a copy or iterate backwards with a for-loop.  Do beware that this code is otherwise very dangerous and can cause a permanent memory leak.  Calling a control's Dispose() method is not optional.  Consider that you may be well ahead by simply making the control invisible, set its Visible property to false.  Solves both problems.

Comment: I second this.  Just make the control enabled=false visible=false when the case is met.

Comment: I would use the Visible property, however the case that calls for the buttons to be removed also, may have the form be rebuilt with the submit/cancel buttons in different locations.

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes sense. It was somthing simple i was overlooking -_-  strange that it works with other control types however.